# This expression has type int -> int but is here used with type int

Tags: types, syntax, ocaml

> Write a function `rindex l e : 'a list -> 'a -> int` that takes a list and a single element and returns the position of the last occurrence of that element in the list (indexed by zero). You should return -1 if the element is not in the list.

This is my attempt, but I get the error “`This expression has type int -> int but is here used with type int`”. What's worong?

```
let rec finderd l e n r=  
  match l with [] -> r
  |(h::t) -> if h=e then (finderd t e (n+1) n) else (finderd t e (n+1) r);;
let rindex l e =(finderd l e 0 -1);;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a very common downside of the syntax. Should be:

```
let rindex l e =(finderd l e 0 (-1));;
```

Otherwise it recognizes `0 -1` as an expression.

Comment: wow, thx, i spend half hour trying to figure this out, stupid ocaml

Comment: If you want to avoid the parens, you can use, `~-` and `~-.`, as the unary equivalent.

Comment: RTFM is a pretty harsh criticism in any situation. The understanding of -1 has an implicit and conditioned meaning in ones mind; a paradigm shift needs to occur in the users mind to realize that `-` is a function of two arguments, not a symbol of unary negation. This is something that reading a manual will not make.

Comment: iirc, (-1) is stressed in every ocaml tutorial. I believe that asking (and answering) questions which are covered in tutorials/manuals is rude wrt work of people who have written that tutorial.

Comment: @ygrek: Hmm, I personally like answering questions about languages that I haven't used for a long time. If I ever wanted to use ocaml for any project again, I'd read the manual, tutorial, whatever. But I don't need to and I've got other things to do. However exposing myself to a little bit of it from time to time just keeps my mind fit. But maybe I'm just being rude. I apologize then.

Comment: @julkiewicz, that's my personal opinion, no need to apologize